# ScalarQueryParameter return Type Error :"List object not callable"

Tags: python, google-bigquery

While setting parameters for bigquery, I encountered Type Error of "List Object is not callable"

```py
title=input()
query = """
   SELECT title 
   FROM `<some BigQuery table>`
   WHERE title LIKE '@title'    #parameter to pass into the query
   ORDER BY title DESC
   LIMIT 100;
"""

params=[
   bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('title', 'STRING', title) 
]
job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.query_parameters=params
query_job=client.query(query,job_config=job_config)
```

Expecting the code to run, but Type Error comes out on the line:

```py
params=[
    bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('title', 'STRING', title) 
]
```

many thanks.

Comment: Not sure what your input is, so hard to tell, but try using `raw_input` instead of `input` for input that is just strings, which seems fitting in this situation, as `input` will try to evaluate the input you give it, so if for example you write `[1, 2, 3]` when asked for input, it will evaluate to a pythonic list.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error message you are getting from BigQuery and your exact table structure as seen from the webUI

Comment: You need to remove the quotes from the reference to the parameter in the query itself, too.